# How to simplify $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n \tan^{-1} \dfrac{2r+1}{r^4+2r^3+r^2+1}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, summation

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n \tan^{-1} \dfrac{2r+1}{r^4+2r^3+r^2+1}$$

How am I supposed to do it? One thing I see here is

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^n \tan^{-1} \dfrac{2r+1}{(r^2+r)^2+1}$$

Here derivative of $r^2+r$ is $2r+1$. (if it helps)

It's final answer is

> $\pi/4$

Comment: What you're adding are a bunch of angles. Maybe draw the corresponding right triangles (putting the relevant angles next to one another) and come up with some argument from there?

Comment: @Arthur After adding values of $r=1$ and $r=2$, I got $\tan^{-1}(3/5)+\tan^{-1}(5/37)$ = 0.67 radians = 38 degrees. But adding like that manually so many times won't make any sense.

Comment: Unless, if you _draw_ the triangles, you can find some geometrical proof that the opposite leg never gets infinite, but diverges, for instance. I dunno, it was just an idea.

Comment: @Arthur I don't think drawing would help. The answer is one algebraic trick away rather than in a geometric insight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hint**

Since $$\dfrac{2r+1}{(r^2+r)^2+1}=\dfrac{(r+1)^2-r^2}{1+r^2(r+1)^2}$$ then
$$\tan^{-1} \Big(\dfrac{2r+1}{(r^2+r)^2+1}\Big)= \tan^{-1}(1+r)^2- \tan^{-1}(r^2) $$ which beautifully telecospes.

Comment: So is there any use of limit or is it just for a show coz I am getting the answer without any use of it.

Comment: It just telescopes !!

Comment: @manshu It's not _just_ for show. $\sum_{r = 1}^\infty$ is short-hand for $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r = 1}^n$, so the $\lim$ would actually be there anyway, just hidden away in notation.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't too far from the answer. Credit on discovering what $(r+1)^2$ was. 
Write $r^2+r$ as $r(r+1)$. Squaring that would give you $r^2$ and $(r+1)^2$. And the difference of those two terms is the numerator. Now, it's in the form of $\tan(A-B)$.

Now, telescope this sum which becomes 
$\arctan(r)- \arctan(1)$

$\pi/2 - \pi/4 = \pi/4$

Comment: thanks. but this is already covered in the answer given by claude.

Comment: @user230452. You are totally right. I was editing (typing the actuel first line) when your answer came (just check at what time I edited). $+1$ for your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. I up voted your answer too.